# Geometric tiling puzzle

Tags: geometry, puzzle, tiling

yesterday my sister send me a YouTube link about a tiling puzzle game: https://youtu.be/A9KU_gPOaGU.

[image]

[image]
Can one deduce from the geometry of the pieces alone whether there is something special about this puzzle in a mathematical sense? Can it really be the hardest tiling puzzle that can be designed with 66 parts? I am a little skeptical about that.

Best regards.

Comment: One can always imagine a harder puzzle than the so-called hardest one...

Comment: The fact that the symmetry involved is generally fivefold (angles like $108^\circ = 3\pi/5$, $144^\circ=4\pi/5$, etc.) and the length ratios being given suggests at least to me that this is probably based on one of the classic kites-and-darts or rhombs Penrose Tilings; my first guess would be that it's 'hardest' in the sense that it's got a particularly small number of distinct pieces and large number of total pieces while still having a unique solution, but quantifying that is tricky.

Comment: I have included two graphics in order it's more handy to consult the question.

Comment: As said by @Steven Stadnicki, the first figure looks to come from the tiling represented [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/791848)

Answer (score 1):

Yep, that it's based on one of the classic kites-and-darts or rhombs Penrose Tilings is also my guess. I'm trying out a few things right now. When I find a substitution for the tiles I will post it.

I cut out some pieces from paper, and they can be put together well. So probably the frame can be filled very quickly, but only almost. That probably makes it difficult.

Comment: Explicit decomposition into kites/darts: see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvMja.png)