# Generating Penrose Tilings from high dimensional lattice projections

Tags: projection, tiling

Enticed by [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3921619), I wrote some python code to generate lattice projections from 7-dimensional cubic lattices, as I was interested to see if a heptagrid tiling also exist.

Basically I generated a 7-dimensional orthonormal basis that had irrational components, then choose 5 of the base vectors as the orthogonal space of my projection, and projected grid points that were at a cutoff distance from the 2-dimensional complement that intersected the $(0,0,0,0,0,0,0)$ lattice point at the origin. The best looking example I was able to get was this: [image]

However, for the most part the results seem to require lots more than 2 shapes, and here comes my question:

> **Question:** Do criteria exist that should be satisfied the projection basis in order for getting proper Penrose tilings?

I imagine there are some special symmetries that the basis choice should fulfill in order to result in proper tilings, but I wonder what those might be, or how to compute such basis. My ultimate goal was to build Penrose tilings for 3-dimensional space, hopefully the criteria I am looking for will not be specific to a number of dimensions

According to [this reference](http://cs.williams.edu/%7Ebailey/06le.pdf), a possible criteria is that the projections of the cubic lattice basis add up to zero:

$$ \sum_{i=0}^6 { \gamma_i} = 0 $$

Comment: take $\vec{a}_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3.5}}\left (1,\cos(\frac{2\pi}{7}),\cos(2\frac{2\pi}{7}),\cdots ,\cos(6\frac{2\pi}{7}) \right ), \vec{a}_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3.5}}\left (1,\sin(\frac{2\pi}{7}),\sin(2\frac{2\pi}{7}),\cdots ,\sin(6\frac{2\pi}{7}) \right )$ as basis of the plane $P$ works pretty well, though I don't know the reason.